# Date Picker doesn't seem to implement Localization

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am using the JQuery Datepicker. When I look through the Debugger I can see my code go through the Localization file and then but when I hover over region I don't see it in the list all I see are en, en-us. **However even thought the Calendar is appearing in English (Should be fr-CA)** when I select a date on the Calendar it posts it in French. Why would the French mode be working only on the date selected.

Hope I have posted this correctly.

```js
$(
function () {
 
 $('[id^="ctl00_PageContentPlaceHolder_DT"]:not([readonly]),[id^="ctl00_PageContentPlaceHolder_UN_EffectiveDate"]:not([readonly])').each(  
 function () {
  var oldValue = $(this).val();
  $(this).datepicker({
   changeMonth: true,
   changeYear: true,
   yearRange: "1970:2060",
   dateFormat: "d M yy",
   defaultDate: "1 jan 2017",//FiscalYearStart, //"1 Jan 2017",
  
   beforeShow: function (input, inst) {
    setTimeout(function () {
     inst.dpDiv.css({
      top: $(".datepicker").offset().top + 35,
      left: $(".datepicker").offset().left
     });
    }, 0)

   },
   
   onClose: function () {
    $(this).focus();
   }   
  });
  $(this).val(oldValue);
 });

 
 
 // Set the language of the datepicker
 var lang = (gLanguage == "E") ? "" : "fr-CA";
 var test = lang
 $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional[lang]);

 var FiscalYearStart = $('input[id$=FiscalYearStart]').val();
});
```

```js
/* Canadian-French initialisation for the jQuery UI date picker plugin. */
(function (factory) {
 if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {

  // AMD. Register as an anonymous module.
  define(["../widgets/datepicker"], factory);
 } else {

  // Browser globals
  factory(jQuery.datepicker);
 }
}

(function (datepicker) {

 datepicker.regional["fr-CA"] = {
  closeText: "Fermer",
  prevText: "Précédent",
  nextText: "Suivant",
  currentText: "Aujourd'hui",
  monthNames: ["janvier", "février", "mars", "avril", "mai", "juin",
   "juillet", "août", "septembre", "octobre", "novembre", "décembre"],
  monthNamesShort: ["jan", "fév", "mars", "avr", "mai", "juin",
   "juil", "août", "sep", "oct", "nov", "déc"],
  dayNames: ["dimanche", "lundi", "mardi", "mercredi", "jeudi", "vendredi", "samedi"],
  dayNamesShort: ["dim.", "lun.", "mar.", "mer.", "jeu.", "ven.", "sam."],
  dayNamesMin: ["D", "L", "M", "M", "J", "V", "S"],
  weekHeader: "Sem.",
  dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
  firstDay: 0,
  isRTL: false,
  showMonthAfterYear: false,
  yearSuffix: ""
 };
 datepicker.setDefaults(datepicker.regional["fr-CA"]);

 return datepicker.regional["fr-CA"];

}));
```

Comment: Please add the dependencies to your code snippets! If you use datepicker with locales you can use `$(function() {
    $("#datefield1").datepicker($.datepicker.regional['de']);
    $("#datefield2").datepicker('option','dateFormat','dd.mm.yy');
});`

Comment: Should I apply this to both JS files or just the Localization file

Comment: you don‘t apply it in this files, you call it out of your (html?)

Comment: OK I don't think it is the calendar, it might actually be an encoding problem I have tried a different calendar and receive the same problem. For example I click on Dec and I should get Déc but I get D&e instead. I tried changing the localization and it had no effect. Funny the calendars work fine in the classic ASP but not aspx.